# How to fix columns to fit 50% on each side of the row?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have simple `table` with min 4 columns (up to 30) in a row. I need to split rows in half and each side to be fixed to `50%`, with same columns on each side.

Example:

```
table.content{ width: 100%;}

<table class="content">
  <tr>
    <td>#1</td>
    <td>Left Side</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</td>
  
    <td>#1</td>
    <td>Right Side</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I this example, I need `3x3` columns to be 50% of the width, so first 3 column = `50%` and next 3 columns `50%`. The text is not fixed, so can be a simple 1,2,3 numbers or a lot of text, like in example.

I have examples of `2x2` up to `15x15` columns in a row.

Is this possible in CSS, without JavaScript?

**Additional info:**

Column's widths need to be per content, not fixed.

I'm trying to achieve similar as [GitHub shows changes](https://github.com/octocat/linguist/compare/master...octocat:an-example-comparison-for-docs?diff=split#diff-e56a8d50b1a75fc4212ffb3504faa007R27)

Edit2:

I tried with `colgroup`, like this:

```
colgroup {width: 50%;}

<colgroup>
  <col>
  <col>
  <col>
</colgroup>
<colgroup>
  <col>
  <col>
  <col>
</colgroup>
```

But it doesn't look right, [see example](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GH3JMJRF0XJJ)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one you can easily separate them into two different parts by using `nth-child` pseudo class selector and set the `width` of each group to `50%` divided the number of `td` are in the group in your example is `3`

```css
table.content {
  width: 100%;
}

td:nth-child(1),
td:nth-child(2),
td:nth-child(3) {
  width: calc(50% / 3);
}

td:nth-child(4),
td:nth-child(5),
td:nth-child(6) {
  width: calc(50% / 3);
}
```

```html
<table class="content">
  <tr>
    <td>#1</td>
    <td>Left Side</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</td>

    <td>#1</td>
    <td>Right Side</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

or you can make column group `colgroup` and easily set the width at each column group

Comment: This will fix the width to 50%/3, right, even if column has only '1' in it? I just added Additional info, as I can't fix the columns to 33% on each side. I need widths to be per content.

Comment: you continue to make some edit at the groups of `td` but the better choice is to make `colgroup` and set its `width` to `50%`

Comment: Like this: <colgroup width="50%"><col1><col2><col3></colgroup><colgroup width="50%"><col1><col2><col3></colgroup> ?

Comment: If you look at github example you can see the width of first column are fixed, while the other adjust as you change browser width - and each side stays at 50%.

Comment: just like that `colgroup{width: 50%;}`

Comment: It doesn't look right: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GH3JMJRF0XJJ

Comment: just see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup)

Comment: It takes more effort to answer the question so it's good idea to mark it as accepted if you do

Comment: You have up vote, right? I think my edit, just after your answer shows that fixing columns to 50%/3 is bad solution, if a column contains only a number '1'. I mean if you want I can accept it, but who would want to hard-code column widths like that?

Comment: I want to leave it open if somebody will provide better solution, no? If after a few days nobody will suggest alternative solution, yours is best and accepted. sounds good?

Comment: that's great you have to wait for the best one

Comment: @MikeTorrettinni If the solution isn't 100% sufficient then there's no point to mark it as accepted even if it's the only answer...